# Async controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I checked the System.Web.Mvc.AsyncController in MVC 4.0, it has the comment "Provided for backward compatibility with ASP.NET MVC 3." does this mean there is a new implementation of async controller in MVC 4? what's the correct way in MVC 4.0 enable async a controller in order to put the I/O intense operations in other thread pool other than IIS request thread pool?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting from ASP.NET MVC 4, you can now use the `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` class as the base class and leverage the TAP (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern):

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Index() { 

     return View(await GetThingsAsync());
}
```

Note that you don't have to use `async` and `await` keywords which come with C# 5.0 but they make asynchronous programming much, much easier and more maintainable.

Have a look at the following articles:

- [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)
- [My Take on Task-based Asynchronous Programming in C# 5.0 and ASP.NET MVC Web Applications](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/my-take-on-task-base-asynchronous-programming-in-c-sharp-5-0-and-asp-net-mvc-web-applications)
- [Asynchronous Database Calls With Task-based Asynchronous Programming Model (TAP) in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asynchronous-database-calls-with-task-based-asynchronous-programming-model-tap-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: Doesn't `async` and `await` come with C# 4.5, not 5.0?

Comment: @Spook there's no C# 4.5: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Versions async/await language support came with C# 5.0 and it also needs .NET 4.5. You may use .NET 4.0 and leverage the async/await language features with a NuGet package from the BCL team: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/